# Disable socket timeout, via setsockopt()

Tags: c++, sockets, timeout, berkeley-sockets

Say I have the following code in C++ that will set the time out for a socket:

```
struct timeval time_val_struct = { 0 };
time_val_struct.tv_sec = 1;
time_val_struct.tv_usec = 0;
return_value = setsockopt(this->m_fdSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(const char*) &time_val_struct, sizeof(time_val_struct));
    if (return_value == -1)
        return;
```

How do I disable the timeout using the same command?

Comment: Either C or C++. Thery are different languages! Said that: what did you try? What about the documentation of the functions is unclear?

Comment: The same code works when compiling in C++, in fact I am compiling this very code with a C++ compiler for a project. therefore the tag of C++ is applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the timeout value to 0. This will do the trick.

```
struct timeval time_val_struct;
time_val_struct.tv_sec = 0;
time_val_struct.tv_usec = 0;
```

A reference can be found here: https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket

> If the timeout is set to zero (the default) then the operation will never timeout

Comment: Works. Is there a way to set everything to default values?

Comment: @A.Smoliak: I don't think that there is a way to set all socket options to the default values. At least I don't know any way to do this.

Comment: There is no magic command to reset the defaults. You should query the socket for its defaults before changing them, then you can restore them later as needed.